# How to remove this space(margin) from a QWidget form

Tags: c++, qt, margin, qt5

I have a `QWidget form`, then I have added `QTextEdit` on the form, but there is a space(margin) in the top.

[image]

I tried to use the following:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
widget->layout()->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
```

But unfortunately, it did not do what I want.

How to remove that space(margin) to be like the `left`, `right` and `down` side ?

---

**Full code**

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
QTextEdit *TextEdit = new QTextEdit(widget);
QMdiSubWindow *mdiWindows = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(widget);
mdiWindows->setGeometry(5, 5, 300, 250);
mdiWindows->setWindowTitle(finfo.baseName());
mdiWindows->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
mdiWindows->layout()->addWidget(TextEdit);
mdiWindows->layout()->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
TextEdit->setText(cache);
widget->setMaximumHeight(0);
mdiWindows->show();
```

Comment: It looks like the extra space is in either the non-client area of the window or in a parent window of whatever control you are using. Load up Spy++ and check out the window hierarchy and see if it's a [C++] class that can easily accessed and/or subclassed or a window that can be easily resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try addding a

```
widget->layout()->setSpacing(0);
```

Comment: But why this function `setSpacing()` control in the upper side only ?
because I have increased the function parameter to `15`, then I have seen the upper side only has been increased, not all sides.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the **menubar**? Try removing it if you don't need it.

Also, try to position the `QTextedit` properly on central widget by clicking the widget and using arrow keys to make its position exact.

Also, there might be a layout causing this problem. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't menu bar, also I have created `QWidget form `and `QTextEdit` dynamically, by code not by Qt designer.

Comment: Well, can you add the UI generating part of your code, that much which would generate same UI on here where I can check out?