# How to remove whitespace above text in a QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtextedit, qlabel

Whenever I shrink a `QTextEdit` box, the lower half of the text gets cut off.

I can get a text label to display the way I want by using a style sheet, but I'm not sure it can accept live inputs. How do I get the full text to display in the `QTextEdit` box?

Example of Issue and how I want it to look:

[image: Cutoff Text]

Comment: Looks like you are working with a "single line" of input/text, have you tried using a QLineEdit?

Comment: Thank you, that worked, my only thing is that I am inheriting this gui. I am trying to keep the same boxes to avoid any negative effects when I go to add inputs, do you know how to edit the QPlainTextEdit itself, or would QLineEdit function the same.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? edit a qplaintext?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.  You can use the QLineEdit to edit text inputs, but it is designed to edit a single line of text.  For instance: First Name, Last Name, Phone Number, etc.  If you are editing inputs with multiple lines (notes, comments, multi-line addresses, etc.) you will need to use a QPlainTextEdit or QTextEdit.

Comment: @Marker I just found out the boxes were chosen arbitrarily, I'm just going to use the QLineEdit. I will accept the answer if you put it down below.

Comment: @Mohammadreza Panahi change the format of the widget itself.

Comment: @viduwoy, ok, thanks, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are working with a "single line" of input/text, have you tried using a QLineEdit?  You can use the QLineEdit to edit text inputs, but it is designed to edit a single line of text. For instance: First Name, Last Name, Phone Number, etc. If you are editing inputs with multiple lines (notes, comments, multi-line addresses, etc.) you will need to use a QPlainTextEdit or QTextEdit.

Answer (score 0):

Review the "Font/Point Size" within the QWidget section of the QT designer when you select the plaintext widget. The looks as though font is larger than the size rectangle for the widget.

Also try using the following suggestion:

[How to remove this space(margin) from a QWidget form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289676/how-to-remove-this-spacemargin-from-a-qwidget-form)

Comment: The overhead white space remains the same regardless of point size.